# React and JSX: exchange two divs, if button is pressed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I´m new to React and JSX and I want to exchange two divs. I´ve done it with Bootstrap 4, JSX and React (Typescript). 
I got multiple rows with cols and want them to change 1:1.

`

```
<row> --- <row>

<col> --- <col>

<col> --- <col>

</row> --- </row>
```

`
...

```
How can I do this only with JSX on the css side.
The button use the  this.sidechange on onClick.
```

```
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">

                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick={this.sideChange}>change the two divs</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <h1>test</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col"><h1>test 2</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

... and more rows and cols.

Code for the button:




sideChange(event:any) {        
        if (stat === 0) {  //
            stat = 1;      //reverse
//code for changing

}
else{
stat = 0;
//code for changing
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your code what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar added

Comment: why do you need to change html tag instead of that you can render conditional div one at a time

Comment: conditional rendering also works after first render?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58852836/6544460 and let me know... is this you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { status: false };

  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ status: !prev.status }));
  };
  render() {
    const { status } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleToggle}>Toggle</button>
        <div className="row">
          {status ? (
            <div className="col">
              <h1>test 1</h1>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="col">
              <h1>test 2</h1>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: almost... but I don´t want to replace it, I want to change the order of them

Comment: @J.Doe order means what?  can you explain me little more because it's conditional rendering which will happen as you click to change